# how jersey process is different from CGI and servlet?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, jersey, restful-architecture

I am newbie to web services.i am trying to understand jersey implementation of restful. i have some doubt that i googled it but could not get satisfactory answer

As we know following life cycle phase of servlet :

> **Loading and instantiation**: At the time of instantiation servlet
>   container call init(ServletConfig) this method is called only once in
>   whole life cycle of servlet. Key point is that container will create
>   object only once in whole life cycle of servlet.
>
> **Service** :Once Loading and instantiation is done each request coming to
>   this servlet handle by service method.Now  for next request container
>   will not create object of servlet again it create separate thread to
>   handle newly coming request.This is one of the major cause of good
>   performance of servlet over CGI application because (In CGI every time
>   there's client request, HTTP server creates new instance of process to
>   serve this request. This is performance killer).
>
> **Destroy** : Container calls destroy() method to indicate to a servlet
>   that the servlet is being taken out of service. This method is only
>   called once all threads within the servlet's service method have
>   exited or after a timeout period has passed.

Am i right ?

Now comming to second part what i got when we create resource in jersey for each comming request container create seperate instance of resource class as we can see each time constructor is called.

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
     public MyResource(){
     System.out.prinln("hi");
     }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

My question is how jersey process is different from CGI ? if not why people compromise with performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java CGI vs. Servlets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401465/java-cgi-vs-servlets)

Comment: I know Java CGI vs. Servlets that's why i explained it in question, i want to know how jersey is different from these?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) specification says (section 3.1.1 of the JAX-RS 2.0 spec)

> By default a new resource class instance is created for each request to that resource. First the constructor (see
>   Section 3.1.2) is called, then any requested dependencies are injected (see Section 3.2), then the appropriate
>   method (see Section 3.3) is invoked and finally the object is made available for garbage collection

So yes, there are some similarities between JAX-RS resource classes and a CGI script.  But the major difference is that it is significantly cheaper to create a new object and garbage collect it than it is to fork/exec a new process.  I would argue that for super high performance JAX-RS could be slower than Servlets.  The implementation is up to you to decide what works best.